# How to execute hdfs zkfc -formatZK with ansible

Tags: hdfs, ansible, ansible-2.x

How can I execute `hdfs zkfc -formatZK` in an ansible playbook?
I try with:

```
- name: format hdfs
  command: hdfs zkfc -formatZK
```

This is the result:

```
fatal: [172.16.8.231]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "hdfs zkfc
-formatZK", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No existe el archivo o el
directorio", "rc": 2}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a good description of what your problem is. Can you show an error message?

Comment: I have update the question @udondan

Comment: And when you manually run the exact same command on the host it works?

Comment: Yes it works correctly, and I execute all the hdfs cluster manually after configuring with ansible and its works, but when I want to execute with ansible I cant. @udondan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your ansible command runs under different user than when you run it manually. This commands needs to be run as hdfs user.

You also need to run with `-nonInteractive` parameter.

```
- name: format ZooKeeper HA state
  command: /usr/bin/hdfs zkfc -formatZK -nonInteractive
  become: yes
  become_user: hdfs
  run_once: yes
```

Comment: Really thanks Misko, it works perfectly, But What is for "-nonInteractive"? and "run_once"?

Comment: `-nonInteractive` option aborts if the name directory exists. `run_once` specifies that this task runs only once if it applies to more hosts (in my case I have multiple namenodes, so it does not run twice). Probably not relevant for your case, sorry.

Comment: is it possible to start zkfc on different VM other than namenode VM ?